# Find index of max value in each row of 2D array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have the following code:

```
amplitude=[]
for i in range (0,160):
    amplitude.append(i+1)

#print(amplitude)

#split arrays up into a line for each sample
traceno=10                  #number of traces in file
samplesno=16             #number of samples in each trace. This wont change.

amplitude_split=np.array(amplitude, dtype=np.int).reshape((traceno,samplesno))
print(amplitude_split)

#print the maximum value of array along axis=1
max_amp=np.amax(amplitude_split,1)
print(max_amp)

#print the  indices of the maximum values along axis=1
ind_max_amp=np.argmax(amplitude_split, axis=1, out=None)
print(ind_max_amp)
```

I would like to find the indices for the max value in each row of the array. 
I am currently only getting `ind_max_amp = [15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15]` which I presume is the column of each max value.

What I need is tuples: (0,15) (1,15) etc...

Also, could anyone help me finding the index of 90% and 10% maximum in each row?

n.b. this is just test code and the max of my real data won't all be in the final column

Comment: You can use zip function:
`print(list(zip(ind_max_amp, max_amp))`

Comment: @CristianContrera `max_amp (which is np.amax)` returns the maximum value rather than index. I think this question asks for indices.

Comment: @Ehsan says: ***What I need is tuples: (0,15) (1,15) etc***  then I do that xD

Comment: @CristianContrera Please go ahead and run your code (regardless of missing parentheses type), your code output is: `[(15, 16), (15, 32), (15, 48), (15, 64), (15, 80), (15, 96), (15, 112), (15, 128), (15, 144), (15, 160)]`. And this is just the example. The question asks for : _**I would like to find the indices for the max value in each row of the array.**_

Answer (score 0):

You can get the maximum value for each row via `np.amax` using `axis=1` and `keepdims` to keep each maximum value in a separate row, and then use `np.argwhere` to find the index of that maximum value in each row.

This will give you a list of indices tuples you want:

```
ind = np.argwhere(amplitude_split==np.amax(amplitude_split,1, keepdims=True))
list(map(tuple, ind))
```

output:

```
[(0, 15), (1, 15), (2, 15), (3, 15), (4, 15), (5, 15), (6, 15), (7, 15), (8, 15), (9, 15)]
```

Comment: Could you explain how this works please?

I am getting output: name 'ind' is not defined

Comment: @okvoyce just edited it with explanation and fix the typo. Please go ahead and accept the answer if this is what you wanted so others can find it helpful too. Thank you.

Comment: Also, as for _**index of 90% and 10% maximum in each row**_, could you explain a bit more what you are looking for? Is it for this specific array you created or for general case? And if it is for general case, are you looking for indices of values that equal to 90%(/10%) of maximum in each row?